# Using path="*" for un-permitted paths shows briefly on valid path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have inputted a route for invalid path handling. For example if a user goes to
`"/random-unattributed-path"` which hasn't been outlined in the router.

It works great, bar a single issue I have found so far.

This is the code I inserted:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={[<Navigation key={0}/>, <Home key={1} />]} />
    <Route
      path="/AboutUs"
      element={[<Navigation key={0} />, <AboutUs key={1} />]}
      key={0}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/Profile/:id"
      element={[<Navigation key={0}/>, <Profile key={1} />]}
    />
    <Route
      path="/Profile"
      element={[<Navigation key={0} />, <Profile key={1} />]}
    />
    <Route path="*" element={[<NotFound />]} /> 
    {/* THIS LINE RIGHT HERE ^^^^^^^^^^^^ */}
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

What I have found, is that when you redirect from one path & element to another, is that it will very very briefly show the notFound element.

I have an example to show this problem here: https://giphy.com/gifs/9ZcdbA169kJy48QB4b/fullscreen

This Code-sandbox demonstrates the code but not the issue, maybe it has something to do with how Code-sandbox works or in my case of the issue, something to do with local-hosting deployment.
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-tereshkova-ptb6nn?file=/src/Other.js

This shows going from `/profile/:id` to `/profile` back to `/profile/:id`

Comment: *Other than* the route `element` being a little odd I don't see any overt issue with this code. How exactly are you navigating around the app, from one route to another? Can you edit to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]? Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I actually already made a demo in Codesandbox but Could not replicate the issue, not entirely sure why, I will add the link though for reference. @DrewReese

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. How are you running the app locally? In other words, what is possibly different between running it locally and the sandbox version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue I see is in your `Navigation` component. It is rendering `NavLink` components from `react-bootstrap` which render a raw anchor tag and `href`.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-bootstrap";

...

<NavLink className="tiny-scale" href={"/"}>
  ...
</NavLink>
```

This is sending a page request to the server and reloads the app.

You will want to render the `NavLink` component from `react-router-dom` to correctly handle navigation client side.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-bootstrap";
import { NavLink as BaseNavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Navigation</h1>
      <NavLink as={BaseNavLink} className="tiny-scale" to="/">
        <span className="Main-element"> home </span>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink as={BaseNavLink} className="tiny-scale" to="/other">
        <span className="Main-element"> other </span>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink as={BaseNavLink} className="tiny-scale" to="/deadlink">
        <span className="Main-element"> dead link </span>
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit using-path-for-un-permitted-paths-shows-briefly-on-valid-path]

I mentioned also the "odd" `element` prop in a comment above. It's more common to create what are called [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) to render common UI elements like the `Navigation` component.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from "./Navigation";

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Navigation />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

...

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";
import Other from "./Other";
import Layout from "./Layout";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/Other" element={<Other />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: I still get this issue with these changes

Comment: @ABpositive You still see the `NotFound` component render momentarily? Can you edit your post to include exactly how you are running the app, and the exact steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yea, I was but after deploying the application it seemed to fix it, your solution seems to have fixed this problem perfectly, though I will make sure to continue testing. thankyou for your extensive answer.